# Basement Ceiling Insulation, Next Step?

Tags: sound-proofing

So I have tenants that live on the first floor, and I live on the second floor. Both levels have hardwood floors in this 1920s duplex I own and there can be some loud noises due to the flooring so I added some insulation to the basement to help. I started with a little section.

Picture: https://ibb.co/Prb8XKq

I used 3.5-inch Owens Corning mineral wool but noticed I still have a lot of room. Could I add faced fiberglass insulation under that, then add some furring strips to have room for wires, and toss up some simple sheetrock? Or is that a waste in your opinion...

The rim joists are sprayfoamed, along with a tiny crawl space, and newer windows so really just looking for sound absorption. Plus the basement is a shared space for laundry and the added insulation idea is for a bit more privacy.

What would you do next?

Comment: Resilient Channel is an option. It's doesn't work well if you don't get your screw locations just right, so if you're a sloppy builder, then forget about it. Or maybe it just doesn't work well, period, and they blame the installer when he complains.

Comment: "in your opinion" is an off-topic question. One person might be fine with the noise, someone else might not. Also, there are already a _ton_ of questions under [tag:sound-proofing] - you should check those out since that's really what your question is about, not "basement" insulation. (Presuming you're in the US, "basement" is below grade, "first" floor is main entry level from the ground, and "second" floor is up one flight of stairs."